# compare two columns from two files and print mix of columns from both input files

Tags: awk

I understand this is a common question but I am tripping up on what will hopefully be simple solution.

I want to match columns `1 and 2` in `TEST_FILE_2.csv` with columns `2 and 3` in `TEST_FILE_1.csv` and for matching lines print `columns 1 and 2` from `TEST_FILE_2.csv` followed by `columns 4 and 5` from `TEST_FILE_1.csv` and finally `column 3` from `TEST_FILE_2.csv`.

I have search many methods but keep coming up short. see my latest effort below

```
awk -F ',' 'NR==FNR{ a[$2,$3]=$4; next } { s=SUBSEP; k=$1 s $2 }k in a{ print $0,a[k] }' text_file1.txt.txt text_file2.txt.txt > TESTDUMMY
```

I am stuck at only managing to print the whole line from `test_file_2` and only `column 4` of `test_file_1` (and not in the desired order).  Thanks a lot for any help.

test_file_1.csv

```
302932,181,352,1709810.639,5683471.356
302933,181,353,1709825.639,5683471.356
302934,181,354,1709840.639,5683471.356
302935,181,355,1709855.639,5683471.356
302936,181,356,1709870.639,5683471.356
302937,181,357,1709885.639,5683471.356
302938,181,358,1709900.639,5683471.356
302939,181,359,1709915.639,5683471.356
302940,181,360,1709930.639,5683471.356
302941,181,361,1709945.639,5683471.356
302942,181,362,1709960.639,5683471.356
302943,181,363,1709975.639,5683471.356
302944,181,364,1709990.639,5683471.356
302945,181,365,1710005.639,5683471.356
302946,181,366,1710020.639,5683471.356
302947,181,367,1710035.639,5683471.356
302948,181,368,1710050.639,5683471.356
302949,181,369,1710065.639,5683471.356
302950,181,370,1710080.639,5683471.356
```

test_file_2.csv

```
181,353,25
181,359,66
185,260,55
189,361,12
181,368,3
```

Desired Output

```
181,353,1709825.639,5683471.356,25
181,359,1709915.639,5683471.356,66
181,368,1710050.639,5683471.356,3
```

Current Output

```
181,353,25 1709825.639
181,359,66 1709915.639
181,368,3 1710050.639
```

Comment: There are multiple answers in the proposed duplicate on how you can tackle the problem. All you need to do is redefine the field separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could do:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$1,$2]=$3;next} ($2,$3) in a {print $0","a[$2,$3]}' test_file_2.csv test_file_1.csv
302933,181,353,1709825.639,5683471.356,25
302939,181,359,1709915.639,5683471.356,66
302948,181,368,1710050.639,5683471.356,3
```

- `FNR==NR {a[$1,$2]=$3;next}` read file 2 and stor column 3 in an array with id as column 1 and 2
- `($2,$3) in a` test if column 2 and 3 from file 1 is found in array
- if so, print line from file 1 and filed 3 from file 2

If you do not need first column from file 1, you can do:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'FNR==NR {a[$1,$2]=$3;next} ($2,$3) in a {print $2,$3,$4,$5,a[$2,$3]}' test_file_2.csv test_file_1.csv
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$1,$2]=$3;next} ($2,$3) in a {f=a[$2,$3];sub(/^[^,]+,/,"");print $0","f}' test_file_2.csv test_file_1.csv
181,353,1709825.639,5683471.356,25
181,359,1709915.639,5683471.356,66
181,368,1710050.639,5683471.356,3
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. They all seem to work but the output has the last column on the next line no matter where I open it and if i just run it without writing to a new file I don't get the final column? Any ideas?

Comment: @charliemit011 maybe your files are in dos format?  Try `dos2linux yourfile`.  I hva just copied and pasted your example above and it works fine.

Comment: that worked perfectly!- thank you for your help

Comment: @charliemit011 If answer works, then you can accept it :)

Comment: What if there are two records in test_file_2.csv like `11,111,...` and `111,11,...`?

Comment: @oguzismail fixed,  made more robust.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but here you need to use the combined `$1$2` to capture the information from file2 in an array, and then use the combined `$2$3` when checking if the combination is present in file2, e.g.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    NR==FNR {a[$1$2]=$3; next} 
    $2$3 in a {print $2,$3,$4,$5,a[$2$3]}
' tf2.csv tf1.csv
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your files in `tf1.csv and`tf2.csv`, respectively, you just copy/middle-mouse paste into the terminal to test, e.g.

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '
>     NR==FNR {a[$1$2]=$3; next}
>     $2$3 in a {print $2,$3,$4,$5,a[$2$3]}
> ' tf2.csv tf1.csv
181,353,1709825.639,5683471.356,25
181,359,1709915.639,5683471.356,66
181,368,1710050.639,5683471.356,3
```

Comment: This is more ore less 100% what I did post, only that you do miss last field. 25,66,3

Comment: No your miss last column, read my post again. Your line `181,353,1709825.639,5683471.356` my line `181,353,1709825.639,5683471.356,25`

Comment: I did miss that and then fix it -- thank you for catching it.

Comment: And then it will be like mine.....

Comment: After you removed your comma separating `$1,$2`, then your second attempt will be similar.